# Is google drive api rounding the file size when calculating in MB / GB?

Tags: google-drive-api

Using the Google Drive REST API after uploaded to drive has a different file size when calculating into MB but the bytes size is the same, I believe that is the rounding error or Is there any another reason why?

Example: My local machine(Windows OS) file size has 9.92 MB(1,04,06,738 bytes), after uploading to google drive its say 10 MB(1,04,06,738 bytes), Bytes size is the same